# react-navigation change Drawer close space color

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I would like to change the close space color to more transparent. In [document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer), I cant find any related to this.

[image]

Comment: lol. Black screen and Black drawer! This must be a tough situation. I hope you find a good solution.

Comment: @BrightLee default is very black, i want to set more transparency, but not sure where to set. Btw, design are follow what designer need, haha

Comment: I bet it is. looks nice by the way. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look this.

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1927

Looks like there are several ways to achieve it.